# Dependency Injection - Should complex, single instanciation be abstracted by a factory?

Tags: java, c#, dependency-injection, factory

I have a service developed using heavily dependency injection. This service is instanciated at application start-up a single time, it is then used as a singleton (not using the Singleton pattern). Instanciating it and its dependencies is complex: some of the dependencies need to be decorated several times, in the correct order, some dependency instances need to be shared through several other dependencies, and some should not.

I do not use a Dependency Injection Framework and do not plan on using one, to keep consistent with the rest of the application. Currently, the service instanciation is in a method that looks like this:

```
private IMyService CreateMyService(IService service, ILoggerFactory logFactory, 
                                   IHttpClient client, IShareRessource sharedRessource)
{
     var decoratedClient = new Decorator3(new Decorator2(new Decorator1(client);
     var subService1 = new SubService1(sharedRessource, logFactory.Create());
     var subService2 = new SubService2(sharedRessource, logFactory.Create(), service);

     return new MyService(decoratedClient, subService1, subService2);
}
```

This is a simplified example in C#, but my question would work in other languages such as Java.

Even though the service is instanciated a single time, at application start-up, should this method be encapsulated in a Factory class? My understanding is that Factories are used when needed to create an instance several times in an application.

Were do you usually instanciate your complex services when using dependency injection without a framework?

Comment: Is the question about if this factory-*method* should be in a factory-*class*? Just think of a factory-class as of any other one: it has *one single purpose*. Now think if that class that currently contains this method even has anything to do with thet method, or in particular if that factory-method breaks the single-responsibility-principle. Only if it does you have a string reason to make your own class.

Comment: Do you create MyService objects also in other scenarios ? If so, a MyServiceFactory.createXyZ() might be a good start. Also the method name could document what type of beast this is. If however, this is only happening once and you don't have other factories around, I would argue that 'code is just another form of dependency injection'. You can easily read and understand what's happening.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your replies. The method above is in a super large class which takes care of instanciating all required services at start-up. In such case, I do believe my _factory-method_ should be moved to a _factory-class_ for the single-responsibility principle. Thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do probably is to refactor the dependency issues (the order shared instances etc) with MyService. But maybe that is not an option in your case.

Dependency injection frameworks such as Spring do support use of a Factory method for creating beans.

I think factories are fine in this case.

Comment: Thanks. What DI issues are you referring to?

Comment: I am refferring to following part of your question "Instanciating it and its dependencies is complex: some of the dependencies need to be decorated several times, in the correct order, some dependency instances need to be shared through several other dependencies, and some should not." - I guess having such a situation is not ideal.

Comment: I understand. Well, I would say dependency injection + separation of concerns (a class should do only one thing) leads to having a tree of dependencies, each encapsulated into one another. Rather than _complex_, I should have said that my service needs dependencies, which each need dependencies themselves, leading to a long list of instanciation. I do not see that as an issue, I would say it's actually pretty healthy. My question was more about how and where to place the instanciation of the service and its dependencies. Thanks again!